# how should i divide a 100GB for ubuntu installation, if i want to have more space in partition where all the softwares, etc. will be installed?

Tags: partitioning

I'm dual booting window with Ubuntu and i have 100 gigabits free space for Ubuntu installation. How much space should i give to /root, /home, /swap, /user, etc. If i want a large space for software and other packages installation and appropriate space for some music files, etc? My system has 4 gigabits of ram.

I had installed it before on another system and gave it 30 gigabits of space with /root having 10 gigabits but it get filled after 2-3 days and now i'm installing it again so want some help to part the space.

If anyone can tell me exact space i should give to the partitions given in the link below:-
https://skorks.com/2009/08/partitioning-your-hard-drive-during-a-linux-install/

under manual partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

This is a preference based question.

I prefer going for a single partition as I am running only Ubuntu on my device. This adds flexibility of adjusting space between your files and software as well. Regarding loss of data, I keep regular backups for safe-keeping in additional hard-disks.

Comment: Sir i had written my preference about the space allocation just need some idea how  much should i give to differet partitions because i don't know generally which partition stores softwares files and which is used for other file and which partition stores ubuntu files itself.

Comment: When you partition, the partition u select for installing ubuntu will store all the software related files while all other partitions will appear as saperate disks
Like C:/ for windows store all software and OS, because u choose C:/ for installation of windows, and D etc are for storing files
Depends on what software you want to install. But in 100GB hard-disk, i'd still prefer not to partition